# Looking for economical ARM based board for learning Linux

Tags: linux, arm

I want to learn embedded linux and porting.

I am planning to buy a Respberry PI which is based on 700 MHz Low Power ARM1176JZ-F Applications Processor, with 512MB SDRAM. 
this is the cheapest board I have found.

My intention is to learn embedded linux and porting. How good is this board for this purpose?

Or shall I look for any other board such as FriendlyARM Mini 2440?

Answer (score 1):

> My intention is to learn embedded linux and porting. How good is this board for this purpose?

I have a pi, it's a great thing for learning about electronics, since you can attach a breadboard to the GPIO pins and get busy.  I'm not sure how useful it would be for learning embedded programming though: the pi itself is a regular PC with an SD card as the boot drive.  However, I know very little about embedded work: if having the GPIO pins broken out, including the I2C bus (an expensive addition to a normal desktop) is useful in connecting whatever little chip, then the pi has that.  You can of course also do bare metal stuff on it.